# AngularJS adding empty option to select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please take a look at this plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/l0NqQmvKXPXluyv0gYO3?p=preview

I have a two inter dependent selects.

Whenever I select a value in the 1st dropdown, then select either `Deployment #1` or `Deployment #2`, and then I proceed to select the organization again, angularjs adds a empty option set to the second dropdown. I have no idea why this happens...

Following is my html code -

```
<select ng-model="temp1">
  <option ng-repeat="opt in data.organizations" value="{{opt.id}}">{{opt.name}}</option>
  <option value="">2</option>
                        <option value="">1</option>
                        <option value="">3</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="temp2" ng-disabled="!temp1">
  <option ng-repeat="deployment in data.deployments | filter : { organizationID : temp1}" 
    value="{{deployment.id}}">{{deployment.name}}</option>
  <option value="">4</option>
                        <option value="">5</option>
                        <option value="">6</option>
</select>
```

Following is my angularjs code -

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);        

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.temp1 = '';
  $scope.temp2 = '';
  $scope.data = {"deployments": [{
    "id": "cd22276d-618b-13f4-94ad-0e0c29669958",
    "name": "Deployment #1",
    "organizationID": "gd28276d-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978",
    "roleID": "cd1dbddf-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978"
  }, {
    "id": "cd22276d-668b-11f4-94ad-0e0c29609928",
    "name": "Deployment #2",
    "organizationID": "cd28276d-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609928",
    "roleID": "cd1dbddf-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978"
  }],
  "organizations": [{
    "id": "gd28276d-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609978",
    "name": "Organization 1"
  }, {
    "id": "cd28276d-668b-11e4-945d-000c29609928",
    "name": "Organization 2"
  }]};  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you switch back, your `temp2 === "Deployment #1"`, but due to filtering, this is not a valid option, so Angular adds an empty one so that you won't accidentally override the ViewModel - in this case `temp2`.

You could fix it, for example, by setting `ng-change="temp2 = undefined"` in the first `select`.